# Missing file birkjour.sty

Tags: packages, compilation-error, journal-publishing

I am trying to submit a paper to Milan Journal of Mathematics. It is requested to use the class birkjour. A .zip with the class is given on the home page of the journal (https://www.springer.com/journal/32/submission-guidelines).

When compiling I get the error birkjour.sty missing. Indeed there is not such a file in the .zip I downloaded. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is `birkjour.cls` not `.sty` so the intended use is

```
\documentclass{birkjour}
```

not

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{birkjour}
```